# Transaction management in dependent services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, nhibernate, architecture

I am interested in the architectural solution of the following moment.

I have:

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IDisposable {
    public GenericRepository(ISession session){
        _session = session;
    };
    public T InsertAsync(T entity){...};
    public IQueryable<T> Read(){...};
    public T UpateAsync(T entity){...};
    public void DeleteAsync(T entity){...};
    public Task Commit(){
        return _session.Transaction.Commit();
    };
    public void Dispose(){
        if(_session.Transaction.IsActive){
            _session.Transaction.Rollback();
        }
    };
}
public class UserService{
    public UserService(GenericRepository<User> repository){...}
    public long CreateUser(string userName){
        ...
        _repository.Commit(); // [1]
    };
}
public class OrganizationService{
    public OrganizationService(GenericRepository<Organization> repository){...}
    public int CreateOrganization(string code){
        ...
        _repository.Commit(); // [2]
    };
}
```

The following registration is used:

```
services.AddScoped<ISession>(x => x.GetRequiredService<NHSessionProvider>().OpenSession());
services.AddScoped(typeof(GenericRepository<>));
services.AddScoped<UserService>();
services.AddScoped<OrganizationService>();
```

These `CreateOrganization` and `CreateUser` can be used independently in any parts of the code:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromServices] OrganizationService service, [FromBody] string code){
    service.CreateOrganization(code);
    return Ok();
}
public IActionResult Post([FromServices] UserService service, [FromBody] string userName){
    service.CreateUser(userName);
    return Ok();
}
```

However, now I have a new service:

```
public class MyBillingService{
    public MyBillingService(GenericRepository<Contractor> repository, OrganizationService organizationService, UserService userService){...}
    public int CreateNewContractor(string organizationCode, string userName){
        ...
        _organizationService.CreateOrganization(organizationCode);
        ...
        _userService.CreateUser(userName);// [3]
        ...     
        _repository.Commit(); // [4]
    }
}
```

In this implementation, `CreateOrganization` and `CreateUser` have their own transactions, and if [3] throws an exception, then the organization will be created anyway.
Ok, because `ISession` is registered as Scoped, then I can delete `_repository.Commit` from `CreateOrganization` and `CreateUser`([1] and [2]). In this case, [4] will be responsible for committing all changes.

But what then to do when `OrganizationService` and `UserService` are used independently? After all, now they have become non-independent services and cannot save data without delegating the commit of changes to some other service:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromServices] UserService service, [FromServices] TransactionService transaction, [FromBody] string userName){
    service.CreateUser(userName);   
    transaction.Commit();
    return Ok();
}
```

As far as this decision **is a good one**?

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/v1.5.2/Unit-Of-Work

Comment: You can implement unit of work design pattern with Begin and Commit methods. In begin method, either you should use the existing transaction if already exists or create a new one. And commit method should commit the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions requires a unit of work. There is no other way to coordinate repositories. The reason you're facing issues here is that your entire design is wrong.

First and foremost, you should not have these repositories at all. You're using EF Core, which is an ORM, and already implements the repository and unit of work patterns. Using an ORM is opting to use a third-party library for your DAL. Wrapping your own DAL layer around that is pointless and imposes needless maintenance and testing costs on your application with *zero* benefit. Your services should depend on your context directly.

Then, services should be self-contained units of functionality. If they depend on other services, you're doing it wrong. The service should correspond with a particular subdomain of your application. If users and organization need to be managed together transactionally, then you should have *one* service that encompasses both.

Alternatively, if you want/need to keep the two separate, then you would need to incorporate the concept of [sagas](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

Comment: Thank! Yes, I already thought about a UoW and most likely this is what I need. In previous projects, I always used the Repository over NHibernate pattern; this gave me some abstraction from ORM.

Comment: I did not understand a bit why services cannot be dependent on other services. Indeed, in this case, I will have to duplicate functionality. Is not it? Is the implementation of MyBillingService from the example a bad implementation?

Comment: First, the repo pattern doesn't serve to abstract a dependency like EF. You still have a dependency, you still have to inject it, and a change to your ORM will *still* leak into your app code. Abstraction likes in patterns like CQRS or microservices. Nothing else is worth your time, though service classes are at least *better* than repos. As for services, there's no technical reason they can't depend on each other, but philosophically they should not. A service should encapsulate your subdomain, so a service depending on another service is a indication of bad design.

Answer (score 1):

So I've started to move more towards what Chris mentioned in his answer and use the ISession directly, but I have used a generic repository in the past.  Your repos can't correctly handle transactions that are already started.

So my generic repo has a couple of methods

```
    protected virtual TResult Transact<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
    {
        if (_session.Transaction.IsActive)
            return func.Invoke();

        TResult result;
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            result = func.Invoke();
            tx.Commit();
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected virtual void Transact(System.Action action)
    {
        Transact(() =>
        {
            action.Invoke();
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Then the methods that are implementing the repo functionality look like this

```
    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        Transact(() => _session.Delete(item));
        return true;
    }
```

This allows the method to use an existing Transaction if it is already started, otherwise create your transaction for this work.

You also should not have a Dispose in your repo since you don't own the reference to ISession.  It's life cycle should be handled by whoever created that instance.

The generic repository also shouldn't have commit functionality except when it is explicitly starting a new transaction.  So now you need to have something that handles starting and committing said transaction.  In a web scenario you are typically in a session per request scenario.  This would mean you are creating your session in BeginRequest and disposing of it in EndRequest.  I then use a transaction attribute to manage creating transactions prior to executing the controller action and commit/rollback after the execution of the controller method.